# How to save refs view ordering in tig

Tags: tig

In tig, I order my refs view by date descending. How do I save this order/sort to be the default?

I can't see this mentioned at all in the manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this issue is not yet solved, sort-field is not configurable in .tigrc
https://github.com/jonas/tig/issues/408